# Ionic Authentication

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have a use case where I need to signup incoming customers in following way

1. The customer visits the site.
2. If the customer is new, then he will register himself on the site with email and phone number.
3. After this, the admin will send the email with OTP to that customer.
4. Once the customer has received the OTP, he can signin to the system and set new password.

I am using Firebase as backend for this and Ionic in the frontend.

I am confused as to how should I go for implementing this?

I was thinking of storing new users in real-time database and once the admin has confirmed then trigger a function to send OTP via mail.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping your using angular

1. Use Firebase Auth
2. Set default route to login screen
3. When customer enters check the firebase auth state if authenticated proceed to home screen
   Note: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {}) can recognize user if previously logged in.
4. I not authenticated show login screen and register screens.
5. Use Firebase auth so it have a parameter called "verified" set to false by default.
6. when admin verifies set verified to true and trigger a cloud function to send Otp.